# Preventing form submission if tokens do not match?

Tags: php, html, forms, csrf

I'm currently working to protect a form I created in PHP/HTML/Javascript from CSRF attacks. I have a class that does two things - one function that generates and returns a random token, and another function that checks if the token exists within the current session and if the tokens are equal. The first one I'll leave out because all it does is generate a token.

```
    public static function checkToken($token) {
        if(!empty($_SESSION['token']) && $token === $_SESSION['token'])) {
            unset($_SESSION['token']);
            return true;
        } 
    return false;
    }
```

On the main page where the form is - I start a session and check if the name of my submit button is equal to its value (which it gains upon submission):

```
    if($_POST['submit_app'] == "Submit" && $_POST['token']) {
        if(Token::checkToken($_POST['token'])) {
            echo 'Token OK';
    } else {
        die();
        }
    }
```

I have purposely altered the token in the Web Development Tools in Google Chrome(F12), yet the form still seems to proceed to my processing page (written in php). Would using `die();` not prevent the other processing form from.. processing? How can I stop the data from being submitted if the tokens do not match?

I know PHP is a server-side language so I may have to do something else to prevent submission, but I'm trying to think of a way I can kill the script before it ever process the data on the form if the tokens aren't the same.

Comment: You're going to have to use JavaScript if you want to prevent submission.

Comment: If the tokens aren't the same, `die` would prevent the execution of remainder of script. That means you either have an error in the `Token::checkToken` logic or simply your first `if` block failed.

Comment: @N.B. Would checking the token in the processing script be a solution? The two scripts are separate so I now see why `die()` wouldn't work. If I wanted to prevent submission, I'd have to use Javascript? I'm not sure how I'd use Javascript inside of PHP, so maybe checking the token in the processing script would be better. Would I have to keep the token check on the same page to prevent CSRF? I don't think I would because a CSRF attack would be potentially changing form data, unless I misinterpret it.

Comment: The code you posted would be fine had it not have a logical failure at the first condition. You can't prevent form submission from occurring using a server-side language, be it C or whatever else because the actual HTTP request happened. You can prevent it on the level of browser, JavaScript coming to mind as the only solution. If I were you, I'd be fine with checking the token in the PHP script and displaying an error message if the failure occurs. There's nothing wrong with that, unless your requests are in megabytes range worth of data.

Comment: @N.B. I'm kinda having a tough time seeing what this code actually prevents, though. It just compares tokens on the same page - it doesn't seem like it actually prevents anything. When I try to mess with the token in the Chrome Dev Tools, it doesn't really change how the form works and it doesn't stop it. The request still goes through and my processing script on the backend still processes things. I don't think I understand CSRF enough..

Answer (score 0):

As you said yourself PHP is a server-side script which can't prevent submitting a form. A form is submitted client-side so, the only way to prevent this is with a client-side script, like javascript.

A CSRF attack is done by embedding a external form in an iframe. What you can do server-side is prevent this behaviour. You can accomplish this with the `.htaccess` X-Frame-Options. To prevent CSRF attack you can use:

```
Header set X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
```

Just add it to your `.htaccess` file. `SAMEORIGIN` setting allows pages to be served in a frame of a page on the same website. If an external site attempts to load the page in a frame the request will be denied. You can also use the `DENY` option here, which should be used if you never intend for your pages to be used inside of a frame.

Note that this won't work for old browsers. Browser compatibility:

- Internet Explorer 8+
- Opera 10.50+
- Safari 4+
- Chrome 4.1.249.1042+
- Firefox 3.6.9+ (or earlier with NoScript)

Comment: I have never heard of `Header set X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN`. Could you explain it a bit further? How does placement work?

Comment: You need to add this in the `.htaccess` file. The htaccess file handles every request before code is executing. The X-Frame-Options HTTP response header can be used to indicate whether or not a browser should be allowed to render a page in a <frame>, <iframe> or <object>. When a external websites wants to include your form in an iframe it will provoke a GET request. When it reaches your htaccess file, it wil recognise that it's not a request of your own server. So if you enabled `X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN` it will deny the request.

Comment: I don't have an `.htaccess` file. I should look into this. I'm just creating some forms/processing forms. It will be placed on a website eventually though.

Comment: On which server do you test your scripts? Apache, IIS, ..?

Comment: I'm using a localhost server (WAMP to be specific).

Comment: You can create an `.htaccess` file in the root of your directory. Then just add the rule and it will work, but it's not easy to test when you run it local. If you don't want to use `.htaccess` than it's hard, because you have to do it client-side. It's pretty difficult to build a "safe" client side script, because it's running on the client and can be modified.